# How to properly test a pyramid_ldap3 based app?

Tags: python, pyramid

Let's say I have this simplified app, named "Alambic". I left out the auth policy stuff, at this point I'm curious about what's the best way to tackle testing in the context of pyramid_ldap3 auth. I can try to get a lightweight repository set up with a minimal working example if the following isn't enough (in which case I'll amend this post).

__init__.py:

```
import ldap3
    from pyramid.config import Configurator

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_ldap3')

    config.ldap_setup(
        'ldap://localhost',
        bind='uid=dummy,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
        passwd='passwd'
    )

    config.ldap_set_login_query(
        base_dn='ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
        filter_tmpl='(uid=%(login)s)',
        scope=ldap3.LEVEL,
    )

    config.ldap_set_groups_query(
        base_dn='ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
        filter_tmpl='(uid=%(userdn)s)',
        scope=ldap3.LEVEL,
        attributes=ldap3.ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
    )
    config.add_route('home', '/')  # No auth
    config.add_route('menu', '/menu')  # Needs LDAP auth
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

views.py:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
@view_config(route_name='menu', permission='auth')
def menu(request):
    ...some code...
```

Now I know about pyramid-ldap-test, which is nice to have a local server to connect against, however I'm stuck trying to get my unittest setup. Getting the db tested is fine (so I left it out here), but for some reason, I can't get the ldap settings to register in my tests. I use testing.DummyRequest, but for some reason all the LDAP data/settings fail to stick even though they are processed correctly. I end up getting a ConfigurationError : pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError: You must call Configurator.ldap_setup during setup to use an LDAP connector.

This is what my tests.py looks like:

```
import unittest
import transaction
from pyramid import testing
import ldap3
from ldap_test import LdapServer    
server = LdapServer(java_delay=1)


class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.config = testing.setUp(settings={})
        self.config.include('pyramid_ldap3')
        self.config.add_route('home', '/')  # No auth
        self.config.add_route('menu', '/menu')  # Needs LDAP auth

        self.config.ldap_setup(
            'ldap://localhost',
            bind='uid=dummy,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
            passwd='passwd'
        )

        self.config.ldap_set_login_query(
            base_dn='ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
            filter_tmpl='(uid=%(login)s)',
            scope=ldap3.LEVEL,
        )

        self.config.ldap_set_groups_query(
            base_dn='ou=people,dc=domain,dc=fr',
            filter_tmpl='(uid=%(userdn)s)',
            scope=ldap3.LEVEL,
            attributes=ldap3.ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
        )
        settings = self.config.get_settings()
        server.start()

    def tearDown(self):

        server.stop()
        testing.tearDown()
        transaction.abort()


class TestHomeSuccessCondition(BaseTest):

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestHomeSuccessCondition, self).setUp()

    def test_home_view(self):
        from .views import home
        info = home(testing.DummyRequest())
        self.assertEqual(info['project'], 'Alambic')

    def test_menu_view(self):
        from .views import menu
        info = menu(testing.DummyRequest())
        self.assertEqual(info['project'], 'Alambic')
```